# what is the limitation of Libmicrohttpd?

Tags: linux, http, c++, c

I want to develop a HTTP server based on the library Libmicrohttpd.

And I'm wondering what is the maximum number of users connecting at the same time that Libmicrohttpd can support?

Comment: Please do **not** [crosspost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380071/what-is-the-limitation-of-libmicrohttpd). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Answer (score 0):

#### What is the maximum number of users that can connect at the same time?

This will depend on the resources available on the server, what you are doing with the connections, and how you configure the client application that uses the library.

> All functions are guaranteed to be completely re-entrant and thread-safe. MHD checks for allocation failures and tries to recover gracefully (for example, by closing the connection).
>
> Additionally, **clients can specify resource limits on the overall number of connections**, number of connections per IP address and memory used per connection to avoid resource exhaustion.

Source [The GNU libmicrohttpd Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/manual/libmicrohttpd.html#microhttpd_002dintro)